# Perform a vectorized exponential moving average in octave

Tags: octave, time-series, vectorization, moving-average

In GNU Octave, would like to calculate an n-day exponential moving average of a vector without using a for-loop.

I am able to do this with a for loop but it is inefficient.  I would like to use the filter function, however I am unsure how to get this to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinventing the wheel on octave exponential moving average for a vector is silly.  Just copy and paste `movavg.m` function defined in the octave financial package here: https://octave.sourceforge.io/financial:

```
function [varargout] = movavg(asset, lead, lag, alpha = 0) 
  if nargin < 3 || nargin > 4 
    print_usage (); 
  endif 
  if lead > lag 
    error ("lead must be <= lag") 
  elseif ischar (alpha) 
    if ! strcmpi (alpha, "e") 
      error ("alpha must be 'e' if it is a char"); 
    endif 
  elseif ! isnumeric (alpha) 
    error ("alpha must be numeric or 'e'") 
  endif 
  ## Compute the weights 
  if ischar (alpha) 
    lead = exp(1:lead); 
    lag  = exp(1:lag); 
  else 
    lead = (1:lead).^alpha; 
    lag  = (1:lag).^alpha; 
  endif 
  ## Adjust the weights to equal 1 
  lead = lead / sum (lead); 
  lag  = lag / sum (lag); 
  short = asset; 
  long  = asset; 
  for i = 1:length (asset) 
    if i < length (lead) 
      ## Compute the run-in period 
      r        = length (lead) - i + 1:length(lead); 
      short(i) = dot (asset(1:i), lead(r))./sum (lead(r)); 
    else 
      short(i) = dot (asset(i - length(lead) + 1:i), lead); 
    endif 
    if i < length (lag) 
      r       = length (lag) - i + 1:length(lag); 
      long(i) = dot (asset(1:i), lag(r))./sum (lag(r)); 
    else 
      long(i) = dot (asset(i - length(lag) + 1:i), lag); 
    endif 
  endfor 
  if nargout > 0 
    varargout{1} = short; 
  else 
    plot((1:length(asset))', [asset(:), long(:), short(:)]); 
  endif 
  if nargout > 1 
    varargout{2} = long; 
  endif 
endfunction
```

And invoke thustly:

```
foo = [NaN; 1;4;8;10;-3;3;4;0;0;3;4;5;6;7;8;9];     
lead = 7 
lag = 7
alpha = 'e' 
movavg(foo, lead, lag, 'e')
```

Which prints:

```
       NaN
       NaN
       NaN
       NaN
       NaN
       NaN
       NaN
   3.39851
   1.24966
   0.45742
   2.06175
   3.28350
   4.37315
   5.40325
   6.41432
   7.42128
   8.42441
```

Answer (score 1):

After piecing together the bits from this thread

http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/vectorized-moving-average-td2132090.html

I built this function using Octave's filter function.

```
function meanV = movingEMean(V, window)
  simpleAvg = mean(V(1:window));
  alpha = 1/window;
  X = V(window:end);
  X(1) = simpleAvg;
  meanV = filter(alpha, [1 alpha-1], X, simpleAvg*(1-alpha));
end
```

It starts with the simple moving average as the basis. `V` is the column vector of numbers to calculate the exponential moving average.  `window` is an integer as a number of days. I used 12.

Here is a mathematical explanation of this function.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average

Note that the page uses `2/(n+1)` (where `n` is `window` or the number of days) as `alpha`, but I use `1/n` because that value of `alpha` fits my needs. Adjust `alpha` as needed.

Alternatively, I sometimes need my input and output vector's dimensions to match. I fill invalid values with `NaN` by adding `meanV = [NaN(window-1,1); meanV];` as the last line in the `movingEMean` function. You could also fill it with `simpleAvg` if you want a rough estimate.